# How to change multiple double values in riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am new to riverpod. I want to get the value of `startValue` and `endValue` and then change their values using riverpod.

I tried assigning `state` to the variables but didn't workout well. I am not able to get the start and end values.

**What i have tried**

```
class DoubleNotifier extends StateNotifier<double> {
 DoubleNotifier(): super(0.0);

 double startValue = state;
 double endValue = state;

 }
```

Any idea the better approach to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class DoubleNotifier extends StateNotifier<MyState> {
DoubleNotifier(): super(const MyState(startValue: 0,endValue: 0));

void changeStartValue(double startValue){
  state = state.copyWith(startValue: startValue);
}

void changeEndValue(double endValue){
  state = state.copyWith(endValue: endValue);
}

void changeBothValue(double startValue, double endValue){
  state = state.copyWith(startValue: startValue, endValue:  endValue);
}


}

class MyState {

  final double startValue;
  final double endValue;

  const MyState({required this.startValue,required this.endValue});

  MyState copyWith({double? startValue, double? endValue}){
    return MyState(
        startValue: startValue ?? this.startValue,
        endValue: endValue ?? this.endValue
    );
  }

}
```